# Multiple Accordion on Page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

im using this Accordion ... https://jsfiddle.net/y7czusd7/1/

```
    $(".tab_content").hide();
    $(".tab_content:first").show();

  /* if in tab mode */
    $("ul.tabs li").click(function() {

      $(".tab_content").hide();
      var activeTab = $(this).attr("rel"); 
      $("#"+activeTab).fadeIn();        

      $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active");

      $(".tab_drawer_heading").removeClass("d_active");
      $(".tab_drawer_heading[rel^='"+activeTab+"']").addClass("d_active");

    });
    $(".tab_container").css("min-height", function(){ 
      return $(".tabs").outerHeight() + 50;
    });
    $(".tab_drawer_heading").click(function() {

      $(".tab_content").hide();
      var d_activeTab = $(this).attr("rel"); 
      $("#"+d_activeTab).fadeIn();

      $(".tab_drawer_heading").removeClass("d_active");
      $(this).addClass("d_active");

      $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
      $("ul.tabs li[rel^='"+d_activeTab+"']").addClass("active");
    });
```

as you see i try to use 2 on the same page, but only the first one is working fine, how can i fix that both work?

Thanks!

Comment: both got the same id on Tab-1, tab-2, tab-3....

Comment: You have to add the HTML code as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need unique DOM id on same page that why it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the same Id on both tabs, try changing the seconds one.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/y7czusd7/6/

The changes:

1) You need to give different ID's to objects in your HTML. Duplicate ID's are not valid HTML and as a result JQUERY is finding all the objects with the same id and performing an action upon them. In your case it was hiding the div with the content in both list objects.

To demonstrate how to resolve this I've just used two tabs for brevity, note the **rel** attribute of the **li** and **h3** elements match the **id** attribute of a **div** element. Also the **div** elements with the class **tab_container** now have id's set.

```
<div class="tabs_wrapper">
  <ul class="tabs">
    <li class="active" rel="tab1">Tab 1</li>
    <li rel="tab2">Tab 2</li>
  </ul>
  <div id="con1" class="tab_container">
    <h3 class="d_active tab_drawer_heading" rel="tab1">Tab 1</h3>
    <div id="tab1" class="tab_content">
      <h2>Tab 1 content</h2>
      <p>Tab 1</p>
    </div>
    <!-- #tab1 -->
    <h3 class="tab_drawer_heading" rel="tab2">Tab 2</h3>
    <div id="tab2" class="tab_content">
      <h2>Tab 2 content</h2>
      <p>Tab 2</p>
    </div>
    <!-- #tab2 -->
  </div>
</div>

<div class="tabs_wrapper">
  <ul class="tabs">
    <li class="active" rel="tab21">Tab 1</li>
    <li rel="tab22">Tab 2</li>
  </ul>
  <div id="con2" class="tab_container">
    <h3 class="d_active tab_drawer_heading" rel="tab21">Tab 21</h3>
    <div id="tab21" class="tab_content">
      <h2>Tab 21 content</h2>
      <p>Tab 21</p>
    </div>
    <!-- #tab21 -->
    <h3 class="tab_drawer_heading" rel="tab22">Tab 22</h3>
    <div id="tab22" class="tab_content">
      <h2>Tab 22 content</h2>
      <p>Tab 22</p>
    </div>
    <!-- #tab22 -->
  </div>
</div>
```

2) Your JavaScript also needs tweaking, the click function of the class **ul.tabs li** needs to target the **tab_container** class of the correct **div** element. I've done this by determining the parent of the active tab (which you had already identified) and then using this object to hide all child divs. This is as per below, note the parent container variable and it's use:

```
$("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
  var activeTab = $(this).attr("rel");
  var parentContainer = $("#"+activeTab).parent("div.tab_container").attr("id");

  $("#"+ parentContainer).children("div").hide();
  $("#"+activeTab).fadeIn();        

  $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");

  $(".tab_drawer_heading").removeClass("d_active");
  $(".tab_drawer_heading[rel^='"+activeTab+"']").addClass("d_active");

});
```

The same can be applied to your other click function for completeness.

Hope this helps.